# Cookie Stuffing to Prestashop Affiliate

Tags: cookies, prestashop

i'm stumbling around this problem without results for days now and i need help.

I want to do cookie stuffing using an affiliate link on prestashop (i have an agreement with the client about it)

What i'm trying to achieve is:

- Stuffing an affiliate cookie when a visitor load a web page

I tried stuffing the cookie in many ways:

1. simple img tag
2. simple iframe
3. redirect 302 on htaccess

   Redirect 302 /go/affiliatelink1 https://merchantwebsite.com/psaffiliate17/en/?affiliate=265

None of those methods worked, if i load the web page and then purchase something on a separate page the sales does not get recognised as brought from the affiliate link

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but if you want to track affiliate orders I'd suggest using `Cookie` object in PrestaShop, hook into `actionFrontControllerInit`, check for `$_GET` params, and if you see one for the affiliate just write it to `Cookie`.

Comment: Check if your customer don't has a X-XSS-Protection